# Getting org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

`openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement` when i was trying to set a value for div tag using java script and selenium webdriver.
I am getting a value that is present in the div tag by using

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("markupTextarea"));
String value = element.getText();
```

Once i get the value i am appending some more text to the existing value and executed the below code

```
jscript = "document.getElementById('markupTextarea').innerText = '{panel:title=Day - X |borderStyle=solid|borderColor=#ccc|titleBGColor=#99ff66|bgColor=#ccffff}{panel}" + value + "'" ;

    jscript = jscript + ";";
    System.out.println(jscript);
    js.executeScript(jscript);
```

Doing this i am getting the above mentioned exception. adding/removing  the line:

```
jscript = jscript + ";";
```

is not giving any positive result.

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

Please, could you paste "jscript" string just before you call executeScript ?
It seems the javascript code is not a correct one.  I have no problem with that code.

Comment: I added System.out.println(jscript); and the out put in console is document.getElementById('markupTextarea').innerText = 'content to be inserted';

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't see why ";" is missing. Maybe you can build that code adding step by step and check when fails. Sorry.